# NodeJS event handling mechanism for a use case

Tags: javascript, node.js

Imagine I have the following logic implemented in NodeJS

```
{
    for(list of objects)
    {
        REST API call (callback)
    }

    function callback(){
        if(responseCode != 200)
        {
            setTimeout(function() {
                //try again
                REST API call (callback)
            }, 5000);
        }
        else
        {
          //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Given NodeJS is single-threaded and event based, if the REST API response for object 1 is not 200, timeout will be triggered, in that case will object 2 be able to access the else loop given object 1 callback is still sleeping for 5000 milliseconds ? If yes, how does it work that way ?

Comment: Hi Karthik, 
The answer to your question is "YES" . As you already said that node is 'event based'. What really happens is that when the function setTimeout is executed, its basically registers into the queue with the delay.

[link] https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timers

Main node process keeps track of the events in the queue and if there is anything to be fired/executed that gets executed else it idles out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded (i,e) one process at any point. The way timers works is they put themselves into callback queue with an delay specified by the user. The main process montiors the queue fires the callback accordingly with duration specified. If you want to learn more about how js engine works underhood i recommend you to watch this.
https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 1):

With both node and in a browser AJAX calls are not guaranteed to be completed in sequence... for example after

```
rest_api_call("doit", 1, function(result){ console.log("Result 1"); });
rest_api_call("doit", 2, function(result){ console.log("Result 2"); });
rest_api_call("doit", 3, function(result){ console.log("Result 3"); });
```

it's well possible the output sequence will not be 1, 2, 3 even if everything goes fine (i.e. if there are no errors).

Once an async call is made it's simply added to a unordered pool of calls waiting for response... whichever answer comes first is first served.

A **simplified** model for how it works is

```
function async_call(url, data, result_cback, error_cback) {
    start_new_thread(handler, [url, data, result_cback, error_cback]);
}

function handler(url, data, result_cback, error_cback) {
    try {
        var reply = sync_send_request(url, data);
        async_queue.push([result_cback, reply]);
    } catch(err) {
        async_queue.push([error_cback, err]);
    }
}

function main_loop() {
    for(;;) {
        if (async_queue.length) {
            var acall = async_queue.shift();
            acall[0](acall[1]);
        } else if (timeouts.length && now() > timeouts[0][0]) {
            var tcall = timeouts.shift();
            tcall[1](tcall[2]);
        } else if (mouse_moved) {
            ...
        } else if (needs_repaint) {
            ...
        } else {
            take_a_nap();
        }
    }
}
```